# How to create object of Google DriveService using OAuthParameters

Tags: google-drive-api

I am able to authorize my application using oAuth ( I get Access token and secret in return). I use those to instantiate an object of OauthParameter. My question is as I have added scope for "google drive" during authentication. How can I create an object of DriveService, just the way PicasaService is being created.

```
PicasaService service;
GOAuthRequestFactory requestFactory;
string Picasa_CONSUMER_KEY = "<CONSUMER KEY>";
static string Picasa_CONSUMER_SECRET = "<CONSUMER SECRET>";
public static string Picasa_SCOPE = "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
string Picasa_CALLBACK_URL = "<CALLBACK URL>";
```

This is how I am creating an object of PicasaService

```
OAuthParameters parameters = new OAuthParameters()
            {
                ConsumerKey = Picasa_CONSUMER_KEY,
                ConsumerSecret = Picasa_CONSUMER_SECRET,
                Token = "token received during authentication", 
                TokenSecret = "secret received during authentication"
            };

requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("XYZ", "XYZ APP", parameters);
service = new PicasaService(requestFactory.ApplicationName);
service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```

Now how can I "parameters" to instantiate an object of DriveService?? 
As I already have the scope of Google Drive, and received token, secret during the authentication process, I don't want to do oAuth separately for google drive.

Thanks
Sujit